# Is it possible to opt-out of carrier restrictions on OS updates?

Tags: 8.0, update

There were reports last year that you would be able to opt-out of carrier restrictions on OS updates for windows phone:

http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2012/06/windows-phone-8-to-provide-an-escape-from-carrier-update-tyranny/

Is this still possible or did they drop this idea?

(I ask because I see there was a new version(s) released 12-Jul-2013 but my Lumia 720 still seems stuck on the version from Dec 2012 and finds no updates when I run it manually)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no opt-out for the carrier approval processes, and the only way to get direct updates is to re-flash your device with country-variant firmware.

This functionality was widely rumoured (and Microsoft even alluded to it) but it didn't make the cut. Possibly in 8.1?

Comment: Thanks Nik, I thought that might be the case. (PS: Your profile pic looks familar.. Geekzone forums?)

Comment: Do you have a reference for it not being in WP8 at all?

Comment: @mutex Probably geekzone, though I'm around there too often.

Comment: @RowlandShaw Unfortunately no definitive reference to support that, however I speak from experience (owning a carrier-branded device), the fact that this feature has no mention in the Windows Phone guides on windowsphone.com, and the following two (albeit unofficial) answers on Microsoft Community: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpupdate/why-do-i-need-a-carrier-to-approve-a-microsoft/73d927f2-0915-4f7d-bf19-fea34007ff2a & http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpupdate/amber-update-for-lumia-822/faef4cba-b1ed-4562-8a09-70e95a0093c4